# bootstrapping a node using chef

Tags: docker, chef-infra

Please help me out with the following. I am trying to bootstrap a docker container.  The target is **Ubuntu 14.04**.

```
172.17.0.1 [2016-02-03T04:31:57+00:00] ERROR: Error connecting to https:// chef.shrikant.com/organizations/project/clients, retry 1/5
172.17.0.1 
172.17.0.1 ========================================================================
172.17.0.1 Chef encountered an error attempting to create the client "nodename2"
172.17.0.1 ========================================================================
172.17.0.1
172.17.0.1 Network Error:
172.17.0.1 There was a network error connecting to the Chef Server:
172.17.0.1 Error connecting to https://chef.shrikant.com/organizations/project/clients - getaddrinfo: Name or service not known
172.17.0.1 
172.17.0.1 Relevant Config Settings:
172.17.0.1 -------------------------
172.17.0.1 chef_server_url  "https:// chef.shrikant.com/organizations/project"
172.17.0.1 
172.17.0.1 If your chef_server_url is correct, your network could be down.
172.17.0.1 
172.17.0.1 
172.17.0.1 Running handlers:
172.17.0.1 [2016-02-03T04:33:07+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
172.17.0.1 Running handlers complete
172.17.0.1 [2016-02-03T04:33:07+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
172.17.0.1 Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 01 minutes 18 seconds
172.17.0.1 [2016-02-03T04:33:07+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to 
/var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
172.17.0.1 [2016-02-03T04:33:07+00:00] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report
172.17.0.1 [2016-02-03T04:33:07+00:00] ERROR: Error connecting to https://chef.shrikant.com/organizations/project/clients - getaddrinfo: Name or service not known
172.17.0.1 [2016-02-03T04:33:07+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

Comment: What is your specific problem? What have you tried so far, please edit your question.

Comment: Can you access your Chef server from your workstation, in a browser http://chef.shrikant.com ?

Comment: Yes I am able to access Chef server from my workstation. Above error is occurs whenever i try to bootstrap a node.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like their is a space in the URL that shouldn't be there. Check the `knife.rb` on your workstation.

Comment: I have checked knife .rb, there is'nt any space in url. As a new user stackovrflow doesnt allow more than 2 links in a post so i added spaces myself.